# SELECT com REGEXP

Tags: sql, postgresql, query

seguinte, tenho uma tabela de pessoas:

[nome, matricula, cpf]

O que ocorre é, algumas pessoas que possuem o "mesmo" cpf tem matrículas diferentes. O [mesmo] está entre aspas, porque no banco, há cpfs como nesse exemplo:

1) 00000000000
2) 000.000.000-00

E eu preciso fazer uma query, buscando por um cpf do primeiro exemplo, e que o postgresql "entenda" que a segunda opção também é válida pra mim..

Como fazer isso?

SELECT * FROM pessoas WHERE cpf = ???????

Obrigado

Comment: Tem jeito sem regex tbm, precisa ser com regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na realidade se você não quiser usar expressão regular você pode somente utilizar um `replace`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM pessoas
 WHERE replace(replace(cpf, '.', ''), '-', '') = '00000000000';
```

Onde o primeiro parâmetro é o texto a ser utilizado como base, o segundo é o carácter a ser encontrado e o terceiro é o caractere pelo qual você trocar.

Ou você pode utilizar expressão regular com `regex_replace` onde os parâmetros são praticamente os mesmos, porém o segundo parâmetro aceita expressões regulares e o terceiro que é o escopo (`g`para global):

```
SELECT *
  FROM pessoas
 WHERE regexp_replace(cpf, '[^0-9]+', '', 'g') = '00000000000';
```